# Trying to use multiprocessing queue but unable to get the desired results

Tags: python, multiprocessing, queue

I'm trying to use python `multiprocessing.Queue` in my code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import datetime as dt


def function_to_get_from_q(Queue):
    #while not Queue.empty():
      print(Queue.get())

def collect(Queue):
   for i in range(10000):
      Queue.put([i, (dt.datetime.utcnow() + dt.timedelta(hours=5, minutes=30)).strftime('%H:%M:%S')])

if __name__ == "__main__":
 Q = mp.Queue()
 process1 = mp.Process(target=collect, args=(Q,))
 process2 = mp.Process(target=function_to_get_from_q, args=(Q,))


 process1.start()
 process2.start()
```

I'm expecting that I get all the lists of number and current time. But I'm getting only first element (`[0, '14:53:52']`).
Where did I go wrong?

Comment: You have the `while` in `function_to_get_from_q()` commented-out, so it only fetches one element from the `Queue` and terminates.

Comment: @martineau using while statement is not even printing the first element.

Comment: That's because the logic is wrong — the function shouldn't terminate whenever the queue's empty.

Comment: Can you tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: Yes, see [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73079227/355230) I posted.

Comment: [`Queue.empty()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue.empty) is not reliable due to possible race conditions. It mostly exists because non-multiprocessing versions of `Queue` provide the same method (where it is reliable because there aren't threads or processes involved). The same actually goes for `Queue.qsize()`, and `Queue.full()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `while` loop you have in your code is wrong because you don't want the `function_to_get_from_q()` process to quit everytime it checks the queue and it's empty. In the code below, a special value is `put()` into the queue to indicate that it's the last one.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import datetime as dt

SENTINEL = 'stop'

def function_to_get_from_q(queue):
    while (value := queue.get()) != SENTINEL:
        print(value)

def collect(queue):
    for i in range(10000):
        t = dt.datetime.utcnow() + dt.timedelta(hours=5, minutes=30)
        queue.put([i, t.strftime('%H:%M:%S')])
    queue.put(SENTINEL)  # Indicate end.


if __name__ == "__main__":
    queue = mp.Queue()
    process1 = mp.Process(target=collect, args=(queue,))
    process2 = mp.Process(target=function_to_get_from_q, args=(queue,))

    process1.start()
    process2.start()

    print('fini')
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution using a special *sentinel* value offered by *martineau*, which I have upvoted, is one way. I just wanted to show a second method that uses a `multiprocessing.JoinableQueue`. In this case `process2` would be a *dameon* process that will automatically terminate when the main process terminates since it loops forever trying to get items from the queue:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import datetime as dt

def function_to_get_from_q(queue):
    while True:
        value = queue.get()
        print(value)
        queue.task_done()

def collect(queue):
    for i in range(1000):
        t = dt.datetime.utcnow() + dt.timedelta(hours=5, minutes=30)
        queue.put([i, t.strftime('%H:%M:%S')])
    # Wait for all work placed on queue to be completed:
    queue.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    queue = mp.JoinableQueue()
    process1 = mp.Process(target=collect, args=(queue,))
    # This needs to be a daemon process since it never terminates:
    process2 = mp.Process(target=function_to_get_from_q, args=(queue,), daemon=True)

    process1.start()
    process2.start()

    # We must explicitly wait for process1 to complete to ensure
    # that our daemon process is not prematurely terminated:
    process1.join()

    print('fini')
```

If you don't wish to use a daemon thread, then we must explicitly terminate `process2`:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import datetime as dt

def function_to_get_from_q(queue):
    while True:
        value = queue.get()
        print(value)
        queue.task_done()

def collect(queue):
    for i in range(1000):
        t = dt.datetime.utcnow() + dt.timedelta(hours=5, minutes=30)
        queue.put([i, t.strftime('%H:%M:%S')])
    # Wait for all work placed on queue to be completed:
    queue.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    queue = mp.JoinableQueue()
    process1 = mp.Process(target=collect, args=(queue,))
    # This needs to be a daemon process since it never terminates:
    process2 = mp.Process(target=function_to_get_from_q, args=(queue,))

    process1.start()
    process2.start()

    # We must explicitly wait for process1 to complete so that
    # we know all work has been completed:
    process1.join()
    # Kill process2:
    process2.terminate()

    print('fini')
```